# How to implement a blacklist in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, random, blacklist

How to implement the blackList?
I am trying to keep use of every step and have the final output not output any objects placed within the blackList.
I want the end result to not allow the complete 5-digit name/number within the blackList. 
I want it to put out a 5 digit number that is not blacklisted.
The blackList is a combination of all the Names.

```js
// The random number generator selects 1 of the numbers from each array. The end result is 5 numbers shown on my webpage. 

const firstNumbers = ['8', '0', '3', '7', '9'];
const secondNumbers = ['3', '0', '9', '6'];
const thirdNumbers = ['7', '6'];
const fourthNumbers = ['1', '5'];
const fifthNumbers = ['4', '0'];

// I want to use this blackList array to compare against the result of the 5 random numbers. I want to check the independent numbers above as a group similar to the array below.  
//If the final result of the number generator has the same numbers as my blackList array ex. 00000, 00001... I do not allow it to show on the webpage. 

//Should I name this array the same as the objects above? 

//Is it best to create a json file for the blackList array because it can grow up to 100000? If so how will the code access it and prevent the getRandomNumber from generating a 5 digit number from the list?

const blackList = [
{firstNames: '0', secondNames: '0', thirdNames: '0', fourthNames: '0', fifthNames: '0'},
  {firstNames: '0', secondNames: '0', thirdNames: '0', fourthNames: '0', fifthNames: '1'},
  {firstNames: '0', secondNames: '0', thirdNames: '0', fourthNames: '0', fifthNames: '2'},
  {firstNames: '0', secondNames: '0', thirdNames: '0', fourthNames: '0', fifthNames: '3'},
  {firstNames: '0', secondNames: '0', thirdNames: '0', fourthNames: '0', fifthNames: '4'},
  {firstNames: '0', secondNames: '0', thirdNames: '0', fourthNames: '0', fifthNames: '5'},
  {firstNames: '0', secondNames: '0', thirdNames: '0', fourthNames: '0', fifthNames: '6'},
  {firstNames: '0', secondNames: '0', thirdNames: '0', fourthNames: '0', fifthNames: '7'},
  {firstNames: '0', secondNames: '0', thirdNames: '0', fourthNames: '0', fifthNames: '8'},
  {firstNames: '0', secondNames: '0', thirdNames: '0', fourthNames: '0', fifthNames: '9'},
  {firstNames: '0', secondNames: '0', thirdNames: '0', fourthNames: '1', fifthNames: '0'}
];

// This is the math for the random generator. is this where I would implement the blackList function to read and compare the array against the 5 random numbers that show on the webpage? 

const getRandomNumber = (max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * max);


// This is where getRandomNumbers are defined. How can I use my blackList correctly so that the getRandomNumbers does not show a complete object in the blackList array?

const getRandomNumbers = (if ((firstNumbers[getRandomNumber(firstNumbers.length)]) !== blackList.firstNumbers && (secondNumbers[getRandomNumber(secondNumbers.length)]) !== blackList.secondNumbers && (thirdNumbers[getRandomNumber(thirdNumbers.length)]) !== blackList.thirdNumbers &&
(fourthNumbers[getRandomNumber(fourthNumbers.length)]) !== blackList.fourthNumbers && (fifthNumbers[getRandomNumber(fifthNumbers.length)]) !== blackList.fifthNumbers)
{
  '${firstNumbers[getRandomNumber(firstNumbers.length)]}
   ${secondNumbers[getRandomNumber(secondNumbers.length)]} 
   ${thirdNumbers[getRandomNumber(thirdNumbers.length)]} 
   ${fourthNumbers[getRandomNumber(fourthNumbers.length)]} 
   ${fifthNumbers[getRandomNumber(fifthNumbers.length)]}`;
}
else {
// how would I write this code to loop and repeat the process until it does not match the blackList? how to get the code to properly read the blackList?
};
);


// I see this is telling the getRandomNumbers where to go. This is also where the button is at.

// Is this where I would put the blackList function? This is where the connection to html/css is at also.

const setRandomNumber = () => {
document.getElementById('random-name').innerText=getRandomNumbers();
};

document.getElementById('generate').addEventListener('click', setRandomNumber);


// This is the final step. Should I have an if/else statement here and/or a loop function. I would go back to the getRandomNumbers function if the random output 5 digits are the same as my blackList. If not show the setRandomNumber on my webpage.

setRandomNumber();
```

Comment: It would be very useful to understand what you want to do with it. Are you going to run a validate function before sending a form to check if the name is black listed?

Comment: I want it to exclude 5-digit possible outputs if the 5 digits are in the blackList. It is a complete 5 digit output that has to remain. For Example, const blackList = [
  {firstNames: '8', secondNames: '0', thirdNames: '7', fourthNames: '1', fifthNames: '4'},   Do not allow it to show 8 0 7 1 4 instead show another 5 digit number based off the given const arrays that is not present in the blacklist.

Comment: Since you updated the question on blacklisting a random string that has 5 digits, shouldn't the blacklist have an array of 5 digit strings: ["00000", "00001", "00002" ... ] instead of objects.

Comment: I think that is why I am having a hard time with creating the blacklist. The end result looks as though it is a string of 5 numbers but it is not. It is the end result of five independent objects. I want the blackList to be able to check it's many objects against the getRandomNumbers output. If one of its objects completely match each individual object of the end result getRandomNumbers (or maybe it's setRandomNumber) it loop and getRandomNumbers and the whole process until it does not show an object from the blackList. The numbers have to remain independent and not a string.